# Postgres: How to auto refresh materialized views per interval

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to automatically refresh a materialized view every 15 minutes or does it have to happen in the client code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will have to be done in an external process. As of Postgres 9.3 doesn't offer a way to have the system refresh materialized views itself on a scheduled basis.